# Send JSON output from php function to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, prototypejs

I have a problem,
I'm working to a project in my university, the first step is to build a login form in php that works with AJAX. Now, I'm having some troubles in the function "output" in functions.php file showed below, because it prints me on screen not the protected area (the page after login), but it prints me he content of the JSON file!

**function.php**:

```
# Function to set JSON output
function output($Return=array()){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); # Set response header
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    exit(json_encode($Return)); # Final JSON response
}
```

**client.js**: (**Note**: I must use Prototype JS library for the assignment, so the '$' function and the syntax is based on the prototype documentation for a new Ajax request)

```
$('#login_form').submit( function() {
    new Ajax.Request('./submit.php', {
        method:'post',
        requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            alert("Success");
            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
        }
    });
});
```

**submit.php**:

```
# Check if Login form is submitted
if(!empty($_POST) /*&& $_POST['Action'] == 'login_form'*/){

    # Define return variable. for further details see "output" function in functions.php
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    /* Server side PHP input validation */
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter a valid Email address.";
    } else if($password === '') {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!='') {
        output($Return);
    }

    # Checking Email and Password existence in DB

    # Selecting the email address of the user with the correct login credentials.
    $query = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM USERS WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //$_SESSION['UserData'] = $result;
    if($query->rowCount() == 1) {
        # Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page
        $Return['result'] = $_SESSION['UserData'] = $result;
    } else {
        # Failure: Set error message
        $Return['error'] = 'Invalid Login Credential.';
    }

    output($Return);
}
```

Comment: Note 1: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); # Set response header` - why are you setting Cross Origin headers on a same origin request? Note 2: if you indeed want CORS access, `requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},` - this triggers a CORS preflight check. does your server code handle a CORS preflight check? Note 3: `$('#login_form').submit( function() {` so, you're intercepting the submit action, but you are not preventing the default submit action, so you'll end up with the page that is set as the `action` attribute of the form

Comment: for Note 3:, try `$('#login_form').submit( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... rest of your code ...});`

Comment: Base on your comment that `$` is Prototype `$('#login_form').submit(` will not work - it should be `$('login_form).observe('submit',`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (because you didn't show any HTML at all) that you have a

```
<form id="login_form" method="POST" action="./submit.php">
```

One problem is that you `$('#login_form').submit( function() {` doesn't prevent the default form submit action, so you will get the JSON

Easily fixed:

```
$('#login_form').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
```

Now, two other issues spring to mind

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); # Set response header -
```

why are you setting Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) headers on a same origin request?

if you indeed want CORS access, then

```
requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'},
```

will trigger a CORS preflight check. does your server code handle a CORS preflight check? It doesn't look that way.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the code with preventDefault and I removed CORS because it was redundant! Now work fine! Thank you!